# Using 'modified javascript' need to calculate cumulative sum of product in pentaho kettle

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I am stuck with creating the multidimensional array in 'Modified javascript' step
I have the input like

ID  Product Sale

1   Fruits  10

2   Biscuit 20

1   Fruits  12

3   Beer    29

I am trying to create the javascript to add those columns values in multidimensional array and sort based on 'Product', then will try to sum the sales based on 'Product'.
Expected Output: id 1-> Fruits -sales(10+12)=22
Can you please help to solve this using javascript array or map?
I have done this using kettle steps like 'groupby' but need to solve this by javascript.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? This is a great website for helping you improve a solution but not so good at doing it for you.

Comment: @RobAnthony    var map = {};
map[product] = delta;
var value;
var stock =0;
for (var key in map) {
    value = map[key];
 //if(map.has(key))
 if(key ==  key)
 {
  stock = stock + value;
 }
 else
 {
  stock = value;
 }
}

Comment: Why would javascript be a requirement? Group by will be faster and is the recomended way of doing it. Using javascript instead is a hacky way of doing it.

Comment: @nsousa I am using javascript to improve the coding skills..

Comment: i have one doubt , can any one please tell me about javascript and kettle...all javascript functions can be works inside kettle ('modified javascript') step? I am asking this question because inside javascript i am creating a Map using Map() function but getting error in javascript function..error is Map() function is not defined in this step

Comment: Rupesh, there are various javascript engines, each one having their own functions available. Kettle uses "Rhino" engine, developed by mozilla, and is limited to a set of specific functions. So, it hasn't all javascript functions available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is not possible using javascript. The step "Modified Java Script Value" works in a per row way, so it doesn't have access to the whole set of data, but only to the currently being processed record.

You can accomplish that by using the "Group by" step. In this case, your "ID" or "Product" should be the Group field, while "Sale" should be the "Subject". Finally, the type should be "Sum".